# How to dynamically bound value to a link using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

The problem that I need to generate link on the fly since the link is set in `ng-repeat`. I think I need to execute custom function inside `ng-repeat` loop which gets data from `$http` and pushes link to `$scope.array`. Then bound `href` to `$scope.array[someIndex]`....The problem I don't know if:

- it's the only way
- a good design
- how to implement it

Example:

**HTML**

```
    <div ng-repeat-start="item in items">
        <a href="{{$scope.arrayOfUrls[$index]}}">the link</a> 
           // here execute $scope.getUrl(item ) somehow
    <div class="extra-div">
    <div ng-repeat-end=""></div>
```

**Controller:**

```
$scope.arrayOfUrls= [];

$scope.getUrl = function(url){
    $http.get(url).then(
        function(data){
           arrayOfUrls.push(data.link);

   }
)
}
```

How to execute `getUrl` during `ng-repeat` cycle?

**PS.** I cannot bound `href` directly to `getUrl` function since there is `$http` which eventually result in infinite digest loop.

Also promises can be returned not in order so expecting that first call to `getUrl` will push link to   `$scope.arrayOfUrls[0]` is false assumption.

**UPDATE:**

As @Claies suggested I trie to prefetch links like this:
**Contoller** executes `$scope.loadFeed();`

```
$scope.loadFeed = function() {
    http.jsonp('feed url').then(function(res) {
            $scope.feeds = res.data.responseData.feed.entries;
            $scope.feeds.forEach(function(e) {
                    // prefetch content and links for each feed
                    //hook new entryStateUrl property to feed objects
                    e['entryStateUrl'] = $scope.getEntryStateUrl(e.link); // e['entryStateUrl'] is undefined

                    })
            })



    }
}
$scope.getEntryStateUrl = function(inputUrl) {

    $http.get(inputUrl).then(function(data) {
        // do stuff
        return data.link;

    });

}

            }
```

Now seems like I am trying pre-fetch urls but getting `undefined` for `e['entryStateUrl']`...

The problem maybe about assigning scope variable when $http is not done getting results... Also it seems like there are nested `promises`: `$http.jsonp` and inside it `$http.get`.

How to fix it?

Comment: so to express this another way, you have an array of items, and for each item, you have to use an `$http` call to a server to retrieve a link that pertains to that specific item? Why can't you pre-fetch the links and add them as another property on the item?

Comment: Agree with @Claies - getting the data during ng-repeat doesn't seem the best way to go about it. At some point elsewhere in the code you will have populated items. Since the url depends only on the value of item, you can do getUrl for all of them at that point. That will make your display code much more straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

As this requires UI enhancement, a directive would be a good approach. How about a directive like this ( [JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/amitthk/whbrm2wc/3/) ).  Please note that I am calling $window.open here - you can replace this with whatever the application requires. :-

```
    todoApp.directive('todoLinks', ['$window',function ($window) {
    var directive = {};

    directive.restrict = 'A';
    directive.transclude = 'true';
    directive.scope = { ngModel: '=ngModel', jsOnClick:'&' };
    directive.template = '<li ng-repeat="item in ngModel"><a href="javascript:void(0)" ng-click="openLink($index)">{{item.name}}</a></li>';

    directive.link = function ($scope, element, attributes) {

        $scope.openLink = function (idx) {
            $window.open($scope.ngModel[idx].link); //Replace this with what your app. requires

                if (attributes.jsOnClick) {
                    //console.log('trigger post jsOnClick');
                    $scope.jsOnClick({ 'idx': idx });
                }

        };
    };
    return directive;
}]);
```

When the controller fills the todo items like this:-

```
todoApp.controller("ToDoCtrl", ['$scope','$timeout','dbService',function($scope, $timeout, dbService)
{
    $scope.todo=[{"name":"google","link":"http://www.google.com"},{"name":"bing","link":"http://www.bing.com"},{"name":"altavista","link":"http://www.altavista.com"}];
}]);
```

Usage of this directive is simple:-

```
<div todo-links ng-model="todo"></div>
```